# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь написать функцию для обработки сигнала Post_init, которая будет заполнять данные профиля пользователя на основании данных другого сайта. Сама функция:

```
@receiver(signals.post_init, sender=CustomUser)
def manga_init(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    t, created = TypeForList.objects.get_or_create(type='MG')
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
    }
    url = f'https://myanimelist.net/mangalist/{instance.mal_account}?status=1'
    zap = req.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(zap.text, 'lxml')
    dat = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'list-table'})
    if dat['data-items'] == '[]':
        pass
    else:
        pattern = re.compile("(\{.+?\})")
        field_ = re.findall(pattern, dat['data-items'])
        for item in field_:
            dict_ = json.loads(item)
            if dict_["manga_publishing_status"] == 2 or dict_["num_read_chapters"] == 0:
                continue
            m, creat = TitleList.objects.get_or_create(name=dict_["manga_title"], type=t)
            person_manga = TitleInProgress.objects.create(
                user=instance,
                title=m,
                last_chap=dict_["num_read_chapters"],
            )
            person_manga.save()
```

При попытке запустить проект выдает ошибку

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Для строк кода, в которых я работаю с элементами Beautiful Soup:

```
if dat['data-items'] == '[]':
и
if dict_["manga_publishing_status"] == 2 or dict_["num_read_chapters"] == 0:
```

Хотя данный код (без работы с базой) вполне работает вне Django. Единственное решение данной проблемы нашел в заключении данного блока кода в `try..except`, но после этого скорость загрузки всех страниц возрастает в несколько раз, вплоть до 10 секунд для админ-панели.

Comment: В ошибке написано, что переменные `dat` и `dict_` содержат `None`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev проблема в том, что они не должны содержать `None`, хотя насколько я начал понимать, оно почему-то вызывает инициализацию объекта пользователя раньше чем регистрация и из-за этого запрос уходит на не полный адрес.